# Gradle build failed with an Exception

Tags: android, android-studio

I am quite new to the studio,

I am trying to Run my application

Error  is encountered -

What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

I tried with jdk 1.8  which gave the same error.

So found few answers which said to reduce jdk to 1.7

but the Error still persists

Please Suggest what to do

Gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "innovapptive.com.mworkorder"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'

}
```

Comment: See these : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640314/android-studio-fails-to-debug-with-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexcepti

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28917696/errorexecution-failed-for-task-appdexdebug-com-android-ide-common-process

Comment: Enabling multidex gives me error :   Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/app/ActionBar$NavigationMode.class

Comment: if you're trying to use Multidex you need to provide dependency for Multidex support lib

Comment: Thanks,But how do i do that ....I am Quite new to this .

Comment: dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.+'


}

Comment: I am still getting the same error

Comment: Please Help..this is drving me crazy Error that i am getting   --    Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v7/view/ActionMode$Callback.class

Comment: It should help to solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27284064/2737927

Comment: Hello, can you please add working code if possible ?

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me taken from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640314/android-studio-fails-to-debug-with-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexcepti):

```
defaultConfig {
   multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was: Build-> Rebuild Project

Answer (score 1):

I fllow the first answer and then another problem caused:
**Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.

> java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/umeng/analytics/AnalyticsConfig.class**
>   Then it happened:
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/umeng/analytics/AnalyticsConfig.class
>   So I tried to remove this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile project(':libraries:SlidingMenu')
    compile files('libs/volley_src.jar')
    compile files('libs/Volley_bin.jar')
//    compile 'com.umeng.analytics:analytics:latest.integration'
//    compile files('libs/umeng-analytics-v5.6.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/xUtils-2.6.14.jar')
}
```

It works and I don't know why,I may try the latest Umeng SDK later.
It may work for you if you are using count and analysis SDK.

Comment: What;s more,I tried the latest SDK and it's marked as a suitable version for Android 6.0,It may be the result for the problem,I guess