# Android google play services duplicate entry causing issue with productFlavors

Tags: java, android

Creating an app that has two productFlavors paid and free. Now since I use Google play services for Ads, its giving a very hard time throwing errors one by one, I've been searching on this one for the whole day, and it seems the root cause is the difference in version of play services specified in my gradle.

At the moment, this is the error I obtain:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForPaidRelease'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     com/google/android/gms/internal/zzkb.class

Answers to similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31642819/android-google-play-services-duplicate-entry) point to cross check if similar .jars exist. However I tried my best and I am helpless.

This is my app level `build.gradle` file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        free {
            applicationId = "com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.free"
        }

        paid {
            applicationId = "com.udacity.gradle.builditbigger.paid"
        }
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    // Added for AdMob
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.0.2'
    compile project(path: ':backend', configuration: 'android-endpoints')
    compile project(path: ':joketeller')
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is my top level `build.gradle` file :

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.1.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Desperate to fix this, any help will be highly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: U can try compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2' instead. Also 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2' is available. Maybe it helps, fingers crossed ;)