# com.android.ide.common.process.processexception org.gradle.process.internal.execexception ... finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-7, android-build

I am getting this error every time after I rebuild or clean my android studio project. After I try to run the project three or four times it will be automatically resolved.

[image]

I have already referred to the below links but I can't solve the problem.

- [finished with non zero exit value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29249986/finished-with-non-zero-exit-value)
- [Android Studio fails to debug with error org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640314/android-studio-fails-to-debug-with-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexcepti)

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Could you please include the actual text of the error message instead of just an image? Images are not searchable, and make your question harder to find for future visitors with the same problem.

Comment: Check your gradle, you have some mixed libraries, or repeated libraries, or another issues with libraries.

Comment: Changed a "please help" to a more direct question.