# Cannot build app containing both Azure SDK and Google Play

Tags: java, android, azure, google-cloud-messaging

I am well aware of the reasons behind `app:dexDebug` error in Android. Going through many similar question in stackoverflow and trying every possible solution, I finally traced out the cause of the error. Below are my dependencies:[image]

If the two compiles

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.3'
```

are compiled together, the error is caused. Removing either of the compiles removes the error, but I don't understand why? Google Play is required for cloud messaging while Azure services is required for registering the device to the Azure push notification hub. I don't see any possibility that they share common jar files or have repeated/duplicate class anywhere.

The libs folder is empty.

Any suggestion for the problem?

Comment: If you want people to help you understand an error, it helps if you post the actual text of the error message - otherwise, we are just guessing.

Comment: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2  ---- this is the error message that i have received

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no conflict of  Google play service and azure mobile service compiles. I have a test project with dependencies:

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
compile 'com.microsoft.azure:azure-mobile-services-android-sdk:2.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'`

And sync project with gradle files, it works fine on my side.

To integrate Notification Hubs in Azure Mobile Service, we can refer to [official guide of Azure Notification Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-android-get-started/#configure-a-new-notification-hub) which was updated at 10/15/2015. In this article, it uses `gms` dependency in:
`compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.87'`

By the way, I found the a [thread with the same issue you met](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640314/android-studio-fails-to-debug-with-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexcepti),  maybe it will give you some help.

Comment: Mate this is the exact thing required. Though late thank you for the response. I simply downloaded the "create new app" from azure and just copied the dependencies from the app's gradle to my own project and it worked :) May be this will hep to some one too.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you use a version number instead of the '+' ?

Try this:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
```

Cause maybe the '+' is compiling the 2 import together....

**Edit**: What  is exactly the error trace you have ?

Comment: I tried, but still gives the same error. Beside, in my manifest.xml, i have <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> This should automatically give the correct version of play services.

Comment: As in every app:dexDebug issues, i have `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'. > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2` error after the gradle biuild

Answer (score 0):

Well, Actually both play service and azure service binaries have dependency loop. To solve this issue instead of using generic statement (i.e. 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0' ) use precise one (i.e. for eg. 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0' ) which narrows the compilation area, hence reducing probability of conflicts. Hope this helps