# Android Studio org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException even using multiDexEnabled

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to porting [Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org) on Android. This is my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "hk.ust.symlab.mobiflink"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.apache.flink/force-shading/pom.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.apache.flink/force-shading/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.xml'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/maven/com.google.guava/guava/pom.properties'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:3.8.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-java:1.0.0-hadoop1'
    compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-clients:0.10.2-hadoop1'
}
```

The weird thing is that if I don't include `compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-clients:0.10.2-hadoop1'` then the projects compile and run without errors, otherwise I have this error:

`com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1`

I've already read a lot of questions about this problem (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640314/android-studio-fails-to-debug-with-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexcepti) one), but as you can see I already included the `multiDexEnabled` option (which was necessary already when I included `compile 'org.apache.flink:flink-java:1.0.0-hadoop1'`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio fails to debug with error org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28640314/android-studio-fails-to-debug-with-error-org-gradle-process-internal-execexcepti)

Comment: Are u able to port Flink on android, please let me know ASAP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this add it in your build.gradle in android section

```
    dexOptions {
            incremental = true;
            preDexLibraries = false
            javaMaxHeapSize "4g" // 2g should be also OK
        }

compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
```

then add application class like bellow

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(base);
    }
```

and then mention your application class into your manifest

```
<application
        android:name=".MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
 </application>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer please?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No, it didn't

Comment: ok. have you extended you your application class with Multidex ??

Comment: This can happen when gradle fails to process resources. In your case it happened to be an invalid image file in the drawable folder, in my case it was an error in one of my XML layouts that Android Studio didn't pick up on

Comment: have you extended you your application class with Multidex ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid that I didn't understand your last question.

Comment: add application class to your app which will extend MultiDexApplication.

Comment: I didn't touch the `Application` class

Comment: I ask you sorry, but you can edit your answer so I would understand better what to do with the `Application` class?